# Fetch php json data to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working in php and jquery project and i use ajax for requests to server side

now i have a problem with ajax response from php file

I have the following php code

```
<?php

require 'db.php';
$code = $_POST['code'];

$status = 0;
$count = 0;
$name = "";
$guarantors = 0;
 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE code='$code'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $name = $row['name'];
    $status = 1;    
    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM guarantors WHERE client_code='$code'";
    $resulti = mysqli_query($link, $sqli);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resulti) > 0){
        $guarantors = '[';
        while($rowi = mysqli_fetch_array($resulti)){
        $count ++;
            $guarantors .= '{id:'.$rowi['id'].', name:'.$rowi['guarantor_name'].'},';
        }
        $guarantors .= ']';
    }else{
        $guarantors = "0";
    }
}else{
    $status = 0;
    $returnText = "إسم المستخدم تم إستخدامه من قبل !";
}

echo json_encode(array("status"=>$status,"name"=>$name,"guarantors"=>$guarantors));
?>
```

And i have this jquery code

```
  $.ajax({
    url:"read_client.php",
    method:"POST",
    data: {code:$('.code').val()},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response){
      if(response.status == 1){
var result = $.parseJSON(response);
console.log(result.guarantors.name)

        YAFloader.close()
      }else{
        Swal.fire(
          'error'
        )
        YAFloader.close()
      }
    }
  });
```

Now i want to fetch each `id` and `name` from `guarantors` , but i can't do it

i need help please quick, can any one help my out ?????

thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$guarantors** should be an array:

```
$guarantors = [];
if (mysqli_num_rows($resulti) > 0) {
    while ($rowi = mysqli_fetch_array($resulti)) {
        $count++;
        $guarantors[] = [
            'id' => $rowi['id'],
            'name' => $rowi['guarantor_name'],
        ];
    }
}
```

and then on js side:

```
result.guarantors.map(guarantor => {
  console.log(guarantor.id, guarantor.name);
})
```

Comment: thank you but


i get this console error


Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] 

this jquery code
            var result = $.parseJSON(response);

            result.guarantors.map(guarantor => {
              console.log(guarantor.id, guarantor.name);
            })


php



$guarantors = [];
if (mysqli_num_rows($resulti) > 0) {
    while ($rowi = mysqli_fetch_array($resulti)) {
        $count++;
        $guarantors[] = [
            'id' => $rowi['id'],
            'name' => $rowi['guarantor_name'],
        ];
    }
}